# How to get unit name in hook?

Tags: juju

How can a hook script get the unit id and the service name? Please give me an example in Python and in Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python

```python
from charmhelpers.core import hookenv
unit_name =  hookenv.local_unit()
service_name = hookenv.local_unit().split('/')[0]
```

## Bash

```bash
UNIT_NAME=$JUJU_UNIT_NAME
```

Comment: Uhh... you're answering your own question an actual answer?

Comment: Yes, this is a feature of askubuntu called 'share your knowledge'. I do this when I've been searching way too long for an answer, and finally find it myself. I post a question using the words I put in google to search the answer. This helps me and other people finding this answer in the future..

Comment: If you find it yourself, you can post it.

Comment: might help others @MerlijnSebrechts to cite your source .. https://discourse.charmhub.io/t/the-hook-environment-hook-tools-and-how-hooks-are-run/1047